# To convert decimal value into its corresponding binary

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Binary {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, num;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arr[] = new int[100];
    System.out.println("enter the number");
    num = in.nextInt();
    while (num != 1) {
      j = num % 2;
      num = num / 2;
      arr[i] = j;
      i++;
    }
    for (i = i; i <= 0; i--) {
      System.out.print("The binary number: " + arr[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote this programme to convert decimal input to its corresponding binary value, the programme takes the input but it does not show the output i.e. the binary value. please help

Comment: Check you loop guard: `i>=0`.

Comment: `i = 0`....`while` loop .... `i++` ... `for loop` condition `i<=0`...
Additionally `i=i` looks pretty weird and is quite useless

Comment: Also: `while (num != 1) {` - think about this condition too.

Comment: yeah!! got it...stupid mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was already pointed out, you need to change the condition of

```
while (num != 1) {
```

to

```
while (num > 0) {
```

since your version is prone to an infinite cycle due to the possibility of `num` being 2.

Change the `for` cycle, like this:

```
for (i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  System.out.print("The binary number: " + arr[i]);
}
```

but to be able to do this, you need to know how many elements will you need to use, so change the declaration of `arr` to this

```
int arr[] = new int[(int)Math.ceil(Math.log(num) / Math.log(2))];
```

But to be able to do this, you need to initialize `num` before you declare `arr`. Code is untested, let me know if there are any typos.

Comment: There is no point in calculating the size of the array with complicated mathematical formulas. The start condition he had is almost good - just no need for the `i = i` but rather use `i--`. The array can always be defined as size 32.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, that's a basic formula and I would use it in this specific case, since the code might be rewritten to have an input larger than the bounds of an integer. In that case 100 could prove not to be enough.

Comment: The code was working but with some error in case of large numbers like 234, but after I used the while(num>0) condition the problem got resolved.Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @PranavTyagi, you are welcome. I think your problem came when you had pair numbers. Can you test your code before the fix with 235?

Answer (score 0):

condition should be `while(num!=0){ //do calculations}`

and change the condition of for loop into `for(i=i;i>=0;i--){}`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Integer` class and it's static method `toBinaryString(int i)`. This method converts an int into its binary value and returns it as a String.

If I correctly understood what you are trying to achieve, you could just write:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter the number");
int num = in.nextInt();
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(num);
System.out.print("The binary number: " + binary);
```